# NHibernate Futures query without explicit columns does not return any data

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sphinx

I have a problem with using a Futures query on a query that does not have explicit columns. The query that is problematic is as follows: "SHOW META;" (see http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sphinxql-show-meta.html) This query returns a table that always has two columns and several rows. Now when I execute the query as follows, everything works fine:

`var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SHOW META");

var metaData = query.List(); // metadata is a list of object[] instances of length two`

The variable "metadata" will now contains a list of object[] instances of length 2, where each object[] item in the list contains the value of the first column (Variable_name) and the value of the second column (Variable).

However, when I try to convert this query to a Futures query, I get back a list of object[] instances of length 0:

`var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SHOW META");

var futureQuery = query.Future();

var metaData = futureQuery.ToList(); // metadata is a list of object[] instances of length zero`

In other words, I do get an object[] for each row in the result but there is no data added to it. What am I doing wrong? Or is this a limitation of NHibernate?

Comment: `futureQuery.ToList()` returns rows with all null data?

Comment: No. futureQuery.ToList() returns a List of object[] objects, only the problem is that each object[] object in the list has a length of zero.

Comment: weird, sounds like it's phantom rows. What would the "Show Meta" be reporting on in this batched context?  Is there another batched query before it? or is it just the last query no matter how long ago?

Comment: Yes, there is another batched query before it, namely the one that retrieves the rows. I wonder if the SHOW META query cannnot be batched.

Comment: looks like the bug I'm after which seems to manifest itself in NH 3.3.1 where Futures of SQLQuery are broken

Comment: Ah, so this is a known bug? Hopefully this bug will be solved soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in NHibernate version 3.3.1 where futures sometimes did not work as expected. This bug has been fixed in version 3.3.3 of NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

If i  understood correctly , Future query is only a way to batch your queries not to keep track of object relations in session.

So if this is correct than it treats your future query and normal query as seperate one and you dnt get the  list of objects .

Comment: Well yes, a future query indicates that it can be batched. However, once I call List() it should return the same as ToList() on a non-futures query. The only difference being that the futures query might be batched.